# Why slide show didn't work in live preview?

Tags: jquery, html, css

1-Why slide show didn't work in live preview?

it working in my desktop but when i share it in live preview it didn't work

```
<div class="slide-show-content"><!-- /image gallery slideshow-->
<div class="slide-show-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div  id="app" class="col-xs-12">
                <div id="wrapper-sliderTv">
                    <!-- sliderTV html-->
                    <div id="sliderTV" class="sliderTV">
                        <!-- slidable items in carousel -->
                        <div id="item-0" class="sliderTV__item">
                            <h1>Amélie</h1>
                            <img src="assets/amelie.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div id="item-1" class="sliderTV__item">
                            <h1>Django Unchained</h1>
                            <img src="assets/django-unchained.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div id="item-2" class="sliderTV__item">
                            <h1>Fight Club</h1>
                            <img src="assets/fight-club.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div id="item-3" class="sliderTV__item">
                            <h1>Forrest Gump</h1>
                            <img src="assets/forrest-gump.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div id="item-4" class="sliderTV__item">
                            <h1>Inglourious Basterds</h1>
                            <img src="assets/inglourious-basterds.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div id="item-5" class="sliderTV__item">
                            <h1>Inside Out</h1>
                            <img src="assets/inside-out-2015.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div id="item-6" class="sliderTV__item">
                            <h1>Interstellar</h1>
                            <img src="assets/interstellar.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div id="item-7" class="sliderTV__item">
                            <h1>Léon: The Professional</h1>
                            <img src="assets/leon-the-professional.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div id="item-8" class="sliderTV__item">
                            <h1>San Andreas</h1>
                            <img src="assets/san-andreas.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <!-- optional navigational arrows -->
                        <div class="sliderTV__prev">&#10096;</div>
                        <div class="sliderTV__next">&#10097;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2-why when i used owl carousel slider let some other jquery hidden?

here the problem it hidden when i use in same section the owl carousel

```
            <li class="body">
        <div class="collapse" id="media-one">
        <div class="body-content">
        <div class="icons-default"><!--icons-->
          <div class="icons">
              <ul class="icons-content">
                 <li>
                      <button class="btn" type="button">
                          <i class="fa fa-commenting"></i>
                      </button>
                      <span>comment</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <button class="btn" type="button">
                          <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                      </button>
                      <span>like</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <button class="btn" type="button">
                          <i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
                      </button>
                      <span>share</span>
                  </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="comments"><!-- comments-->
          <ul class="comments-content clearfix"> <!-- item 1-->
              <li class="img">
                  <img src="imgs/media/post-profile.png" alt="//" />
              </li>
              <li class="details">
                  <span class="head">Mohamed Samy</span>
                  <span class="text">
                      Praesent ac condimentum felis. Nulla at nisl orci, at dignissim dolor raesent ac condimentum felis
                  </span>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="comments-content clearfix"> <!-- item 2-->
              <li class="img">
                  <img src="imgs/media/post-profile.png" alt="//" />
              </li>
              <li class="details">
                  <span class="head">Mohamed Samy</span>
                  <span class="text">
                      Praesent ac condimentum felis. Nulla at nisl orci, at dignissim dolor raesent ac condimentum felis
                  </span>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="comments-content clearfix"> <!-- item 3-->
              <li class="img">
                  <img src="imgs/media/post-profile.png" alt="//" />
              </li>
              <li class="details">
                  <span class="head">Mohamed Samy</span>
                  <span class="text">
                      Praesent ac condimentum felis. Nulla at nisl orci, at dignissim dolor raesent ac condimentum felis
                  </span>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </li>
```

i hope my question is clear now

live link

http://atonvision.github.io/mediadata/

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is hidden? The gallery items? Could it be that you are missing some CSS? I don't think the gallery items should be aligned on top of each other...

Comment: check here in media blocks accordion working well in this class"fa fa-list-ul" here http://atonvision.github.io/mediadata/media.html when i used carousel for blocks it working but the accordion get display:none;   http://atonvision.github.io/mediadata/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you included the script that contains `sliderTV` before using that function. I saw the error when I use Firebug.

```
TypeError: $(...).sliderTV is not a function

$('#sliderTV').sliderTV();
```

Comment: any ideas about fix it?

Comment: You have a source of your script there of your slider. The library of your `sliderTV`. It's something like `<script src="...url../somethingLikethis.js"></script>`. Put it at the top of your mark-up or in the header of your HTML.

Comment: sure i added it link and it working well but in my desktop when i share it in live demo it get bug added it links  """<script src="js/sliderTV.js"></script>""""

Comment: He has sliderTV.js in his DOM. But jQuery doesn't load it as a function, so $.sliderTV doesn't result as function.

Comment: @mohamedallam I saw that you put the scripts at the bottom of footer. Try putting it inside the header, along with `<links>`

Comment: @rmondesilva Putting scripts in the bottom of the page is okay. That's not the problem, though I did notice some mess (like adding jQuery twice, in two different versions). Try cleaning this up a little bit, and make sure you load everything in order (according to dependencies).

Comment: @Narxx Yes I know it's not the problem. Yes you're right. His come may be messy that's why I ask him to put slider scripts at the top to escape some scripts that may contain the real cause of problem.

Comment: @rmondesilva same problem i  can add here files and u check it in silent mode?

Comment: @mohamedallam Basically, you haven't changed anything of what we suggested so far, so we have no idea whether our suggestions help you or not... Try ordering your code first. Get rid of duplicate calls for jQuery and such, make the order of JS load reasonable (according to your dependencies) and see from there... I don't know why you don't manage to load sliderTV as function to jQuery. Worth a Google search...